# jQuery ajax : error while passing variables in data

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

just a quick question :

```
 var h = $('#hebergeurJQUERY').val();
 var t = $('#typeJQUERY').val();

function requestData() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '12months/months.php',
     data : "hosting="+h+"&type="+t+"",
......
```

doesnt work while

```
data : "hosting=Something&type=Something",
```

Works.

Any idea to something stupid i did (again ?)
;)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass an object to the data parameter, then jQuery handles all the escaping for you which may be a cause of the problem. You might also have hit problems because of the actual timing of the execution of the code. Put the definition into the function itself:

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'months.php',
        data : {
            hosting : $('#hebergeurJQUERY').val(),
            type : $('#typeJQUERY').val()
        }
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd change the `data` key assignment to:

```
data: {
    hosting: h,
    type: t
}
```

Doing so will cause jQuery to generate the URL-encoded string that I think you were trying to generate here.